# Android constraint not working properly with edit text

Tags: android

I have created a layout with a image and 2 editTexts
http://sodasi.com/android-constraint.jpg

The image is showing up but not those 2 editTexts. I checked for errors and I only have few warning that has nothing to do with my problem

I'm using constraint layout, why those  2 textfields are not showing up?

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Count: 0"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cat_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cat_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cat_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cat_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/category_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Why is rendering properly in Android Layout but not on AVD? it makes no sense
I'm using this in a RecycleView

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this one and check will it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="121dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/count"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Count: 0"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cat_name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cat_name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cat_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Category "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/count"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: it doesn't work. If I add a width it is working. any other ideas?

Comment: You can always remove `ConstraintLayout` and use other container like `RelativeLayout`. That is not complex UI and `RelativeLayout` will fit.

Comment: true, but, I'm new to android, and I'm trying to use the best option I have. I can't just use something else each time I face a issue :D. I will keep digging...

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such a problem and I think that this is a Constraint Layout bug, but fortunately it is easy to get around it, for this you need to wrap the EditText in a FrameLayout or another ViewGroup, set its size to 0dp, and set the EditText size to match_parent

below I have provided a screenshot of the code and representation of my case

[image: my code in xml]
[image: my preview in xml]